# Look like iPhone inbuilt contact applications image selection

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created an application in which i have to add users to the sqlite database.
Now the problem is I want the look of the standard iPhone Contact application Where while adding user we have the width of first cell smaller than other cells and the  image before that cell..

Can you please give me the idea how such thing is possible. 
How to make one cell small and rest others of normal size..

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) messages you can listen for to adjust height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

However, even thought I didn't write Contacts.app I have a feeling they are also using

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

To adjust the views as well.  Remember, you don't have to pack everything into a single monolithic custom table view cell.  You can create multiple custom table view cells and load them each appropriately depending on the index path.

Comment: I knw we can adjust heightr by using the delegates.. but my question was the width.. How to adjust width..I got the temporary solution I have taken the custom view and added it as the table header

Comment: Custom TableViewCell is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The contact detail view is a grouped tableview. Each cluster of cells is a section. The top section is a single custom cell with two subviews that look like squashed tableview cells. The left view shows the contact's photo. The right view shows the name.

To reproduce, create a custom UITableView subclass and lay it out like you want either programmatically or in Interface Builder. Then in the tableview delegate's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check `indexPath.section` and return the proper row for the section.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Contacts app uses a custom `tableHeaderView` when presenting the contact details with an image and label. A similar implementation is included in the sample project [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html). The RecipeDetailView loads a separate nib in `tableViewHeaderView` that is used to set the `tableView.tableHeaderView` property. Have a look at `RecipeDetailViewController.{h,m}` and `DetailHeaderView.xib`. When the Contacts app switches to editing mode, the headerView appears to be swapped out for another view that has a button and a tableView with a single cell. This will allow you to set up a separate tableViewDelegate to handle the Name parts of the contact and a delegate to handle the address / telephony details.